# How to show/print all the variables and pointers names of a program

Tags: c++11, variables, pointers

as from Title, is there a way/command to show all variables and pointers name of a program?

Comment: What would that do?

Comment: something to show all the variables and pointers in a big program: var1, var2, .... pVar1, pVar2.....